# В чём я не прав? Что я не так сделал? В чем моя ошибка?

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Здрасте, я хотел сделать бота для своего дискорда чтобы друзьям было приятно и мне не скучно. Решил я добавить базу данных и даже не представлял что это и как будет у меня гореть, посмотрел в интернете как делается ничего не получилось, полностью переписал с видео ролика код, вставил в моего бота и он не хочет добавлять игроков в базу данных, я решил проверить кого он видет  в этом коде

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот успешно подключен к серверу!')
    

    await bot.change_presence( status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('Sublime (пишет код)') )
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        lvl INT,
        admin INT,
        awarn INT
    )""")
    connection.commit()

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:                
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 1, 0, 0)")
                connection.commit()

            else:
                pass
            connection.commit()
```

и вот вставил я `print(member)` дабы узнать кого видет мой бот при подключении и оказывается он видет только себя! Вот строка из терминала (я на визуал студие)

```
Windows PowerShell
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт, 2009. Все права защищены.
PS C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\games bot> & 
C:/Users/Dmitry/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe 
"c:/Users/Dmitry/Desktop/games bot/bot.py"
Бот успешно подключен к серверу!
 
Games Smoke | Helper#9713 - online
Games Smoke | Helper#9713
```

Помогите новенькому)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас не включены [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, members = True)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]